# Invalid params: unknown field `storageDepositLimit` Error when getting contract data from a chain

Tags: smart-contract, javascript, polkadot-js

I deploy the flipper contract to Jupiter testnet, when I try to get the contract data, I got this error message although it works just fine on a local node. (I also tested on other test networks and the error persists)

```
2022-02-28 10:53:34        METADATA: Unknown types found, no types for AuthorityState
2022-02-28 10:53:34        RPC-CORE: call(callRequest: ContractCallRequest, at?: BlockHash): ContractExecResult:: -32602: Invalid params: unknown field `storageDepositLimit`, expected one of `origin`, `dest`, `value`, `gasLimit`, `inputData`.
Error: -32602: Invalid params: unknown field `storageDepositLimit`, expected one of `origin`, `dest`, `value`, `gasLimit`, `inputData`.
    at RpcCoder._checkError (/home/minhnd/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-provider/coder/index.cjs:84:13)
    at RpcCoder.decodeResponse (/home/minhnd/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-provider/coder/index.cjs:47:10)
    at WsProvider.value (/home/minhnd/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-provider/ws/index.cjs:267:90)
    at W3CWebSocket.value [as onmessage] (/home/minhnd/node_modules/@polkadot/rpc-provider/ws/index.cjs:247:153)
    at W3CWebSocket._dispatchEvent [as dispatchEvent] (/home/minhnd/node_modules/yaeti/lib/EventTarget.js:107:17)
    at W3CWebSocket.onMessage (/home/minhnd/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:234:14)
    at WebSocketConnection.<anonymous> (/home/minhnd/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:205:19)
    at WebSocketConnection.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at WebSocketConnection.processFrame (/home/minhnd/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:554:26)
    at /home/minhnd/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:323:40
```

This is the code file I use to call the contracts:

```
const { ApiPromise, WsProvider } = require("@polkadot/api");
const { ContractPromise } = require("@polkadot/api-contract");
const { keyring } = require("@polkadot/ui-keyring");
keyring.loadAll({ ss58Format: 42, type: "sr25519" });

const abi = require("./freshdi_metadata.json");

async function main() {
    const provider = new WsProvider("wss://ws.jupiter-poa.patract.cn/");
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider });

    const contractAddress = "kabwymmUkz77bD9VHPbugxv75mLHqw8hR8eLhyXFxnmKU8Z";
    const contract = new ContractPromise(api, abi, contractAddress);

    const newPair = keyring.createFromUri("my secret phrase")
    const value = 0;
    const gasLimit = 5000000000000;
    const { gasConsumed, result, output } = await contract.query.get(
        newPair.address,
        { value, gasLimit }
    );
    console.log(result.toHuman());
    console.log(gasConsumed.toHuman());

    if (result.isOk) {
        console.log("Success", output.toHuman());
    } else {
        console.error("Error", result.asErr);
    }
}

main()
    .catch(console.error)
    .finally(() => process.exit());
```

Comment: Sounds like your node is not compatible with your version of polkadotjs. Which node are you using?

Comment: @forgetso You're right. I found out that the testnet I'm using is running on an older version of substrate. I changed to a testnet with the newer version and my code works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason: Compatibility issue. The testnet I was trying to connect to used an older version of substrate.